# Different env files in Laravel feature and unit tests

Tags: laravel, testing

I noticed that Laravel uses .env file in feature tests and .env.testing in unit tests by default.

I want to use only .env.testing file in the both cases. It's possible if I run this command before runing tests:

```
php artisan config:cache --env=testing
```

and after running the tests:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

I wanted to know if there is any simpler solution?

Comment: Delete your existing .env file and create a symlink at .env pointing at .env.testing

ln -s .env .env.testing

Comment: @GilesBennett I need .env file, but not in tests.

Comment: You can specify your .env variables in phpunit.xml for testing. It's a good practice.

Comment: @MaxShaian I tried and add DB_CONNECTION and DB_DATABASE variables in phpunit.xml file, but Laravel gets these variables from .env file in feature tests.

Comment: @G.Baghashvili I've just tested on my local environment and no, tests prioritize these settings. All my test are feature tests.
make sure that your tests are inherited from TestCase

Comment: @MaxShaian I found strange behavior. After running php artisan config:cache it doesn't work, but works after running php artisan config:clear

Comment: @G.Baghashvili I think it's a feature as cached config is not supposed to be in tests, as it has higher priority.